# add content with 2 levels taxonomy in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal, and I'm working with a content panel.

I want to create a news content containing a 'category' taxonomy reference field. However, my vocabulary has 2 levels and over 100 terms, so it's hard to choose an category using the simple widgets.

I don't want to create new add content panel, but the panel of Drupal. So any ideas for that?

Comment: Why not use a different widget? The autocomplete term widget works a lot better for really big vocabularies than the checkbox or select ones.

Comment: I want to have 2 selectbox, one for super category, and one for sub category, when I select a super category, the sub selectbox will show all childs of this cate. But I don't know how to do. Can you help me??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

There's also a tutorial on how to use it at http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/05/29/drupal-7-mutiliple-selection-list-for-taxonomy-using-hierarchical-select/.

(The one caveat is that there isn't yet support for using it with exposed Views taxonomy fields.)

Comment: Thanks so much! It's the module that I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! If this answers your question, mind marking it as the answer? This helps those with similar questions find yours and prevents duplicates. Thanks!